# SQL Injection detected

Tags: sql-injection, laravel

I was loading my sites front end and watching the responses in burpsuite when I noticed a response which contained a very verbose sql error

```
    "message": "SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type bigint: \"1test\" (SQL: select * from \"passengers\" where \"passengers\".\"id\" = 1test limit 1)",
    "exception": "Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException",
```

My question is whether an attacker could inject inside the int value expected by the sql engine.

PS. The error is also sent to the frontend - see pic

- System is Laravel

[image]

Comment: We don't know your system. Is that query exposed to the user in any way?

Comment: Which database ? Please add a tag with the correct DBMS. It depends on the query but that may very well be an exploitable injection vulnerability you got here.

Comment: @Kate: Based on the message it is Postgres.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A direct injection is unlikely, since the error is caused by what *ought to have been* a bigint being cast to a bigint, and raising an exception. So, it's pretty clear that only bigints are going to pass that particular hurdle.

But you have at least one potential problem just right there - what happens if someone passes a *valid* id for something they shouldn't be able to access? This kind of query seems as it should have some form of validation. Some systems allow replacing parameters with an encrypted form of the same (i.e. instead of `type=summary&id=12345` you would get `enc=73a33390e99459324cc2e9c741dd831891638a50fc62ad6f91556f6a0c7621c1` and, of course, replacing characters at random would get rejected out of hand), some others use a simpler hash validation (e.g. `type=summary&id=12345&hash=65823ce5`).

Also, errors being passed back to the UI are *bad*. They're bad for the aesthetics, as they give a stronger impression of unreliability, and they're bad for the information they might disclose. That, at least, ought to be fixed urgently.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the code.

If you use **raw strings** like this

```
...->select( ... )->whereRaw( "id = " . $id )
```

then your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

If you use **parametrized queries** like this

```
...->select( ... )->whereRaw( "id = ?", $id )
```

then SQL injection in such code is not possible.